# ETL - Moving data from Postgres/Oracle to a TripleStore (RDF)

Tags: postgresql, oracle, etl

I'm looking for pointers on how to handle an ETL process that I have to implement for my organization. I know how to query SQL database but i'm not SQL DB specialist. I work more in the sphere of the semantic web and therefore I am more knowledgeable of TripleStore.

I need to move data from a Postgres and an Oracle database to a triple-store. TripleStore use RDF format, so i will need to perform some transformation in the middle. I need to keep the triple-store in synchronization with the source sql database. That is, I need to continuously update the triplestore from what is happening in the sql stores.

it is one way from the sql store to the triples store

Doing my own research, i have red about change data capture, replication, binary replication and etc...

Please could you help me make sense of all of this and guide on where to look to solve this kind of problems?